# How to integrate intentMedia thrid party service on AMP project?

Tags: javascript, amp-html, google-amp

Recently I am developing an AMP project where I need to add intentMedia ( https://intentmedia.com ) third party service to track user record. This third party is totally based on javascript platform. Were I need to set or modify IntentMediaProperties, a global javascript variable based on user activities.

I have tried it through amp-iframe component but could not achieved the goal.

So how I can integrate intentMedia service on AMP project?

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with a few companies like that, some are pretty good and will work with you on becoming AMP compliant. Some aren't interested. Your best bet would be to contact them and see if they offer some form of AMP compliant tracking.

Not sure what their tracking script looks like, but for most of the ones I have dealt with they're typically just building a query string from some variables. AMP has a set of variables that can be used with the [amp-analytics](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-analytics) and [amp-pixel](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-pixel) tags. Check out [this variable list](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md) for the available variables.

Assuming you have a representative you deal with at IntentMedia, contact them with the links provided in this post and see if their developers can help you convert their tracking script to be AMP compliant. Sounds like you're an existing customer, so they may be willing to work with you to make it happen.